# Regex: Capture a subsequent value if a prior word is present

Tags: html, regex, regex-group

I have the HTML below. I want to capture the value of a given label using regex. I am using the capture group to get the value now. However, it is very messy. Below HTML is a very simplified version of what I have. My regex pattern looks somewhat like this to get the `value` (textcontent) of the span following the `Author` label.

```
`/\bAuthor\b:\<\/span\>\s+\<span\s[a-z="]+\>([A-z\s]+)/`

<div>
  <div><span class="label">Author:</span> 
  <span class="value">Someone</span></div>

  <div><span class="label">Place:</span> 
  <span class="value">Some place</span></div>

  <div><spanclass="label">Date:</span> 
  <span class="value">23 Aug 2023</span></div>
</div>
```

Is there a better way to solve this issue?

Note: This is for use in a [chrome extension](https://webscraper.io) that allows scraping of data. And the only option it gives is to use regex.

Comment: HTML parser library ?

Comment: @0stone0 Sorry for not giving context. This is for use in a scraping chrome extension, all it support is regex.

Comment: @esafwan you mean you cant use querySelector?

Comment: Try this regex: `Author[\s\S]*?value">([^<]*)`  It isn't escaped for your environment . It is simpler than your version and it is more obvious what the purpose is: get the first value after an Author.

Comment: @aloisdg Nope, we can only pass a regx pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I think your RegEx looks pretty good. If you wanted to make it a little simpler, maybe these ideas could help.

- If you know the word "Author" appears there, and it's followed by the
  "span" tags like that, maybe you can use more quantifiers for
  matching and you don't have to labor with inclusion of the HTML
  delimiters and word boundaries so much. Just match "Author:" and
  "/span" for example. Maybe that also reduces some of the escaping
  burden.
- Since you're looking for the `span` tag several times, you could wrap
  the first one in its own capture group and simply back reference from
  then on. Makes it a little easier to type and to read.

I work in a different environment, so my code won't look exactly like yours, but I can show you the idea in R. I copied your HTML code to a variable called `a_string` and wrote the Regular Expression in variable `re`. I wrapped each portion of the RegEx in parentheses to form capture groups. My objectives were to get a capture group for "span", which appears in the second capture group in the RegEx and which I'm able to back reference subsequently, and to get a capture group for the author name in between the `span` tags, which is in the fourth capture group in the RegEx.

```
library(stringr)
a_string <- '<div>
  <div><span class="label">Author:</span> 
  <span class="value">Someone</span></div>

  <div><span class="label">Place:</span> 
  <span class="value">Some place</span></div>

  <div><spanclass="label">Date:</span> 
  <span class="value">23 Aug 2023</span></div>
</div>'

re <- "(Author:.+/)(span)(.+\\s.+<\\2.+?>)(.+)(</\\2)"
match_vector <- str_match(a_string, re_pat)
match_vector
match_vector[,5]
```

R lets me vectorize the capture groups. I don't know how your environment references those, but the last two lines of that code print the following, which consists of the whole match vector, and then just the fifth element of that match vector, which is the author name you're attempting to match. I love the capture group trick!

```
> match_vector
     [,1]                                                     [,2]        [,3]  
[1,] "Author:</span> \n  <span class=\"value\">Someone</span" "Author:</" "span"
     [,4]                           [,5]      [,6]    
[1,] "> \n  <span class=\"value\">" "Someone" "</span"
> match_vector[,5]
[1] "Someone"
```